# How can I insert a PHP code in CKEditor from a plugin?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, escaping, ckeditor

I'm using Drupal 7 and the CKEditor module for a WYSIWYG textarea. I need to insert a PHP code like `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` in the Full HTML text format, it isn't needed to see the `Hello World` in the WYSIWYG mode, but it has to be in the source mode.

The config file `sites\all\modules\contrib\ckeditor\ckeditor.config.js` has the `config.protectedSource.push(/<\?[\s\S]*?\?>/g); // PHP Code` line and the Full HTML text format has the `PHP evalutaor` checked.

So, if I write `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` in the source mode **it works perfectly**.

Now I want to add a button in the CKEditor tool bar to add the next code when the button is clicked: `<div id="phpcode"><?php echo "Hello World!"; ?></div>`.

The code in my `plugin.js` is:

```
editor.addCommand('phpcode', {
    exec : function() {
        code = editor.document.createElement('div');
        code.setAttribute('id', 'phpcode');
        code.setHtml('<?php echo "Hewllo World"; ?>');
        editor.insertElement(code);
    }
});
```

But the result is (Notice that the `<?php` and `?>` are commented.):

```
<div id="phpcode"><!--?php echo "Hewllo World"; ?--></div>
```

If I change the `code.setHtml()` for `code.setText()` the result is (Notice that the `<` and `>` are escaped):

```
<div id="phpcode">&lt;?php echo "Hewllo World"; ?&gt;</div>
```

How can I insert a PHP code clicking in a CKEditor toolbar button?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is so easy. Just change the `insertElement` function for `insertHtml` function:

```
editor.addCommand('phpcode', {
    exec : function() {
        editor.insertHtml('<div id="phpcode"><?php echo "Hewllo World"; ?></div>');
    }
});
```